# How to improve my regex to check if number includes a sing in any place and in any amount?

Tags: java, regex, numbers

I want to check if the phone numer includes only numbers, or '+' at the beginning, some '-' or spaces. Now I check if there are only numbers and the '+'.

I want also allow writing a number as 123-456-678 or 123 445 6788. How to improve my regex, which lets have '-' or spaces in any places and in any amout but there aren't obligatory ?

My code:

```
if (clientNumber.matches("^[+]?\\d+")) {
        System.out.println("OK");
    } else {
        System.out.println("ERROR");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regexp should work: `^\+?\d+(( |-)\d+)*` - the number starting with optional `+`, followed by a sequence of digits and then followed by multiple suffixes starting with a single   or `-`.

[Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/4uAyXQ/1)

In Java string this should look as follows: `number.matches("^\\+?\\d+(( |-)\\d+)*")`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```java
clientNumber.matches("\\+?(?:[\\s-]*\\d)+")
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/q1yj89/1).

You need no `^`, `matches()` requires the entire string to match the regular expression.

**EXPLANATION**

```java
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \+?                      '+' (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\s-]*                   any character of: whitespace (\n, \r,
                             \t, \f, and " "), '-' (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )+                       end of grouping
```

Answer (score 1):

or

```java
clientNumber.matches("\\+?(\\d+[ -]*)+")
```

to only allow space and dash and all the digits.

basically, you can do this in many ways and you can test it out on the regex101.com site.